# How to create history data in pinia

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

I am using pinia in my project and I have two array states. Now I need to have the history of the entered data in these states.
For example: every time I push an object to array in state or change the data in an array, I want to be able to push the data of that array in an array in store.
The problem is that by pushing current data of the state in an array in another store, in in all indexes of the new areay, the new value of the first state will be replaced and I can't have the history of changes

The point is that in the first store, pinia's default settings must be available so I can use the features, but in the second store I need the data to be unchanging and only added to array.

Let me also add that for the second store there is no need for using pinia and I would be glad if you could suggest something else. (But whatever feature I use, by changing the state in the first store, my data changes)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [VueUse](https://vueuse.org/) is the correct pick here.

Have you tried *using* (heh) [useRefHistory](https://vueuse.org/core/userefhistory/#userefhistory)? That does exactly what you need: a history of your reactive values.

Recall that you can use [storeToRefs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/modules/pinia.html#storetorefs) to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

Store values need to be watched and accumulated, e.g. with `watch`:

```
watch(
  () => store.myData,
  (data, oldData) => {
    if (!isEqualDeep(data, oldData)
      store.myDataHistory.push(cloneDeep(data)) // should preferably be inside an action
  },
  { deep: true }
);
```

Comment: Could you show isEqualDeep ? Is that a custom function?

Comment: @Whitespacecode isEqualDeep and cloneDeep are some unspecific implementations, e.g. Lodash